# Variable in soup.find_all

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm searching for a way to use a Variable in find_all.
Tried the following way, but it does not seem to work

```
Cl="Class_='m-3'"

Productlist=soup.find_all(Cl)
```

Does anyone have a solution or maybe knows why it isn't working? Help

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all()` method is using with any tag. There is no tag in your example.
Right usage is this:
`soup.find_all("h1", attrs={"class": "title", "id": "itemid"})` or `soup.find_all("h1", class_="title")`